# Connect CloudSQL Postgres Db using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

So I am DevOps engineer please excuse for my lack of knowledge in python development. I am trying to connect a CloudSQL Postgres 14 Db using Python. So that I can insert data and read data from my application. Can someone help me understand why I am getting error when I try to run the python script.

Reference used:  [Stackoverflow reference used for connecting CloudSQL with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67406341/python-script-query-to-gcp-postgresql-db-from-local-machine)

```
# Copyright 2021 Google LLC.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

import os
from google.cloud.sql.connector import connector

# Connect to the database
conn = connector.connect(
    os.getenv("angelic-hexagon-307814:us-central1:sqlpg1234"),
    "pg8000",
    user=os.getenv("test1"),
    password=os.getenv("test1"),
    db=os.getenv("postgres")
)

# Execute a query
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * from accounts")

# Fetch the results
result = cursor.fetchall()

# Do something with the results
for row in result:
    print(row)
```

I have this file with filename sql.py and I run the command `python3 sql.py` to run the python script. But I am getting below error but not able to debug the reason behind this. Can someone help?

```
sidharth@Sidharths-Air python % python3 sql.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sidharth/python/sql.py", line 8, in <module>
    conn = connector.connect(
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.sql.connector.connector' has no attribute 'connect'. Did you mean: 'Connector'?
```

After trying out the solution mentioned by @pensive

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 199, in _make_socket
    sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout, source_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 845, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 833, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3292, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pg8000/__init__.py", line 111, in connect
    return Connection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pg8000/legacy.py", line 443, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 312, in __init__
    self.channel_binding, self._usock = _make_socket(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 201, in _make_socket
    raise InterfaceError(
pg8000.exceptions.InterfaceError: Can't create a connection to host localhost and port 5432 (timeout is None and source_address is None).

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sidharth/python/sql.py", line 15, in <module>
    with db.connect() as conn:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3268, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 147, in __init__
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2430, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3292, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pg8000/__init__.py", line 111, in connect
    return Connection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pg8000/legacy.py", line 443, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 312, in __init__
    self.channel_binding, self._usock = _make_socket(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 201, in _make_socket
    raise InterfaceError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pg8000.exceptions.InterfaceError) Can't create a connection to host localhost and port 5432 (timeout is None and source_address is None).
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/rvf5)
```

After executing what Jack has mentioned getting this error

```
(venv) bash-3.2$ python main.py 
['project:region:instance-name']: An error occurred while performing refresh. Scheduling another refresh attempt immediately
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/instance.py", line 389, in _refresh_task
    refresh_data = await refresh_task
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/instance.py", line 313, in _perform_refresh
    metadata = await metadata_task
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/refresh_utils.py", line 103, in _get_metadata
    resp = await client_session.get(url, headers=headers, raise_for_status=True)
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 669, in _request
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 1011, in raise_for_status
    raise ClientResponseError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 400, message='Bad Request', url=URL('https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/project/instances/instance-name/connectSettings')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/main.py", line 27, in <module>
    with pool.connect() as db_conn:
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3268, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3292, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 365, in <lambda>
    return lambda rec: creator_fn()
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/main.py", line 10, in getconn
    conn = connector.connect(
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/connector.py", line 163, in connect
    return connect_task.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 446, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/connector.py", line 244, in connect_async
    instance_data, ip_address = await instance.connect_info(ip_type)
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/instance.py", line 446, in connect_info
    instance_data = await self._current
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/instance.py", line 389, in _refresh_task
    refresh_data = await refresh_task
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/instance.py", line 313, in _perform_refresh
    metadata = await metadata_task
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/refresh_utils.py", line 103, in _get_metadata
    resp = await client_session.get(url, headers=headers, raise_for_status=True)
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 669, in _request
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 1011, in raise_for_status
    raise ClientResponseError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 400, message='Bad Request', url=URL('https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/project/instances/instance-name/connectSettings')
```

The link said something like this

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "sqladmin.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SqlConnectService.GetConnectSettings"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@sidharth vijayajumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17128041/sidharth-vijayakumar) The post and code sample you are referencing is over 2 years old and using v0.1.0 of the Cloud SQL Python Connector. As of writing this the Cloud SQL Python Connector is now on [v1.4.2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/releases/tag/v1.4.2). There have beens changes to the API since v0.1.0 (major version upgrade.)

I would recommend taking look at this [interactive Python notebook](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/blob/main/samples/notebooks/postgres_python_connector.ipynb#scrollTo=Y33XoYC2H7Hz) to step you through the process of establishing a connection to a Postgres Cloud SQL instance with up-to-date code samples.
The official [Github README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector#usage) is also always up-to-date with usage examples.

Her is a quick code sample showcasing the current way to connect to a Postgres instance using the Cloud SQL Python Connector:

```py
import sqlalchemy
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes


# initialize Python Connector object
connector = Connector()

# Python Connector database connection function
def getconn():
    conn = connector.connect(
        "project:region:instance-name", # Cloud SQL Instance Connection Name
        "pg8000",
        user="my-user",
        password="my-password",
        db="my-database",
        ip_type= IPTypes.PUBLIC  # IPTypes.PRIVATE for private IP
    )
    return conn

# create connection pool with 'creator' argument to our connection object function
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "postgresql+pg8000://",
    creator=getconn,
)

# interact with Cloud SQL database using connection pool
with pool.connect() as db_conn:
    # insert statement
    insert_stmt = sqlalchemy.text(
        "INSERT INTO my_table (id, title) VALUES (:id, :title)",
    )
    # insert into database
    db_conn.execute(insert_stmt, parameters={"id": "book1", "title": "Book One"})

    # commit transaction (SQLAlchemy v2.X.X is commit as you go)
    db_conn.commit()

    # query database
    result = db_conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text("SELECT * from my_table")).fetchall()

    # Do something with the results
    for row in result:
       print(row)
```

Comment: I get an error `(venv) sidharth@Sidharths-Air pythonapp % python3 main.py                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sidharth/PycharmProjects/pythonapp/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
` do you know how to fix this? I tried `pip3 install google` but did not work

Comment: have you properly pip installed the `cloud-sql-python-connector` package?

Comment: I have now done `pip install cloud-sql-python-connector` now getting a new error I have posted in the question

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar you need to update `project:region:instance-name` in the sample I provided to `angelic-hexagon-307814:us-central1:sqlpg123`. That is just a placeholder for your proper instance connection name.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a Cloud SQL database, you can use the pg8000 library along with the sqlalchemy library

to install pg8000

```
pip install sqlalchemy pg8000
```

here is sample for connection

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_user = os.getenv("test")
db_pass = os.getenv("test")
db_name = os.getenv("postgres")
cloud_sql_connection_name = os.getenv("angelic-hexagon-307814:us-central1:test-db")

connection_name = f"/cloudsql/{cloud_sql_connection_name}"

db = create_engine(
    f"postgresql+pg8000://{db_user}:{db_pass}@{connection_name}/{db_name}"
)

with db.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute("SELECT * from accounts")
    for row in result:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer but I am still getting an error

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar can you please let me know the erro

Comment: I have updated my question at the end there is the error